# Angular 5 table with drill-down feature

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I am working on angular 5 and have a requirement to create a table with drill down feature where there can n number parent child components and when you click on parent all the children will be displayed(drill-down). Please find the sample data below.

```
"[{"Id":1,
"ClientName":null,
"ProductName":"Product1",
"CatagoryName":null,
"Jsondata":"[{\"TKey\":\"hubname\",\"TValue\":\"XXXX\"},{\"TKey\":\"IPAddress\",\"TValue\":\"YYYY\"},{\"TKey\":\"Origin\",\"TValue\":\"ZZZZ\"},{\"TKey\":\"Domain\",\"TValue\":\"AAAA\"},{\"TKey\":\"Health\",\"TValue\":\"Running\"}]",
"ParentName":"",
"Name":"XXXX",
"EntityType":null,
"CreatedTime":"2018-02-09T13:20:23.253",
"child":[  
   {  
      "Id":2,
      "ClientName":null,
      "ProductName":"Prod1",
      "CatagoryName":null,
      "Jsondata":"[{\"TKey\":\"AgentName\",\"TValue\":\"BBBB\"},{\"TKey\":\"AgentIP\",\"TValue\":\"YYYY\"},{\"TKey\":\"Agent_Address\",\"TValue\":\"ZZZZ\"},{\"TKey\":\"Response\",\"TValue\":null},{\"TKey\":\"Status\",\"TValue\":\"Running\"}]",
      "ParentName":"XXXX",
      "Name":"BBBB",
      "EntityType":null,
      "CreatedTime":"2018-02-09T13:20:23.257",
      "subChild":[  
         {  
            "Id":2,
            "ClientName":null,
            "ProductName":"CAUIM",
            "CatagoryName":null,
            "Jsondata":"[{\"TKey\":\"AgentName\",\"TValue\":\"CCCC\"},{\"TKey\":\"AgentIP\",\"TValue\":\"DDDD\"},{\"TKey\":\"Agent_Address\",\"TValue\":\"FFFF\"},{\"TKey\":\"Response\",\"TValue\":null},{\"TKey\":\"Status\",\"TValue\":\"Running\"}]",
            "ParentName":"BBBB",
            "Name":"CCCC",
            "EntityType":null,
            "CreatedTime":"2018-02-09T13:20:23.257"
         }
      ]
   }
]
}
]"
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have worked with drilldowns but it's very unclear what you want do you use a javascript library like highcharts or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you wanna achieve but I will do my best. Let's say you click on a table row you can use a popup for it like this:

```
$mdDialog.show({
               template: '<drill-down></drill-down>',
               scope: $scope,
               preserveScope: true,
               targetEvent: event,
               clickOutsideToClose: false,
               controller: BarController,
               controllerAs: 'BarController'
              });
```

I made a component for it and use it in the `template` tag. The `$mdDialog` is from angular itself. After this you can use a nice framework called Jquery Data table in this popup.

link: https://datatables.net/

In this framework you can specify the drilldown data you want. It also supports filtering, pagination and export function like PDF or Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If its expand/collapse you mean use .

```
<table class="table">
<tr><th>...</th></tr>
<ng-container *ngFor="let parent in parents">
 <tr (click)="onParentRowClicked(parent.Id)"[ngClass]="{'row-selected table-active':isExpanded(payment.Id)}">....<tr/>
 <tr *ngIf="isExpanded(repayment)" class="row-selected-content">
    <td colspan="9">
     <child [model]="parent.children></child >
    </td>
 </tr>
</ng-container>
</table>
```

But I personally think it better to use panels/cards when you have several levels that you need to expand and collapse. Its so difficult with all columnheaders in different levels